# Qcqs lemma in Ravi Vakil's notes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Qcqs lemma in Ravi Vakil's notes says that :

> If $X$ is a quasi compact quasi separated scheme and $s\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ then **the natural map** $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)_s\rightarrow \Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is an isomorphism.

I was trying to prove this on my own as this looks related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359861/global-sections-on-quasi-coherent-sheaves-on-affine-scheme). This is more or less a trivial statement in case of affine schemes.  When $X=\text{Spec}(A)$, $s\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=\mathcal{O}_X(X)$.
We have, $X_s=\{\mathfrak{p}\in X:s_{\mathfrak{p}}\notin \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{p}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}\}$.  Identifying $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ with $A$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ with $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ we have $s_{\mathfrak{p}}=\frac{s}{1}\in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
So, $X_s=\{\mathfrak{p}\in X:\frac{s}{1}\notin \mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}\}=\{\mathfrak{p}\in X:s\notin \mathfrak{p}\}=D(s)$.
So, $\Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)=\Gamma(D(s),\mathcal{O}_X)=A_s$. We thus have isomorphism $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)_s\rightarrow \Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Let $X$ be an arbitrary scheme. We have $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow \Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)$, just the restriction map.

In case of restiction map $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow \Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)$, we have $s\mapsto s|_{X_s}$. A section $t\in \mathcal{O}(U)$ is invertible iff $t_x\in \mathcal{O}_x$ is invertible for every $x\in U$. By definition, $s_x\in \mathcal{O}_x$ is invertible for every $x\in X_s$ so, $s|_{X_s}$ is invertible. So, $s^n|_{X_s}$ is invertible in $\Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Image of every element of $S=\{1,s^n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is invertible in $\Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Let $A$ be a ring, $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$ then, we have the notation of localization of $A$  with respect to $S$ which comes with map $\pi:A\rightarrow A_S$ with $a\mapsto \frac{a}{1}$ and with universal property that given any ring $B$ and a ring homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$    such that $f(s)$ is a unit in $B$ for every $s\in S$ then there exists a unique map $g:A_S\rightarrow B$ such that $f=g\circ \pi$.

So, we do have a map $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)_s\rightarrow \Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)$ coming from the  map $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow \Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

I am not able to proceed further. Ravi Vakil has considered some exact sequences but I think it can be done just from the map from restriction. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: By definition of $X_s$, $s$ is locally invertible over $X_s$, i.e. you can cover $X_s$ by open subsets $U$ on which $s$ is invertible. By uniqueness of the inverse element, the local inverses glue to an inverse section defined on all of $X_s$. Hence, you get the induced map $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)_s\to \Gamma(X_s,\mathscr{O}_X)$.

Comment: @user363120 yes this explanation I should have added in the question. So, now how do I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find it helpful to have a look at Hartshorne's $\textit{Algebraic Geometry}$, Chapter II, Exercise $2.16$. In brief:

The map $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)_s \to \Gamma(X_s,\mathscr{O}_X)$ being injective means that given a section $a\in \Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ whose restriction to $X_s$ is zero, there exists some $n$ such that $s^n \cdot a=0$.

For proving surjectivity, note that the intersection of two open affines in $X$ is quasi-compact since $X$ is quasi-separated. Use this to prove that multiplying a section of $\mathscr{O}_X$ over $X_s$ by a suitable power of $s$ you obtain an element which is the restriction of a global section.

If you need some further details, let me know.

$\textbf{Edit}$ For proving the part about surjectivity, let $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)$ be a finite open affine covering of $X$ and let $a\in \Gamma(X_s,\mathscr{O}_X)$. Since the statement we want to prove is true for affine schemes (the restriction map to $X_s$ is simply the localization map in this case), there exists some $m$ (independent of $i=1,\ldots,n$) and elements $a_i\in A_i$ such that $s^m \vert_{X_s \cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)} \cdot a\vert_{X_s \cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)} = a_i\vert_{X_s\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)}$. In particular, $a_i\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_j)} - a_j\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_j)}\in \Gamma(\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_j),\mathscr{O}_X)$ restricts to $0$ over $X_s\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_j)$. Since the intersection of two open affines of $X$ is quasi-compact, we conclude from the injectivity part that there exists some $M$ (independent of $i,j$) such that
$$
s\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_j)}^M \cdot a_i\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_j)} = s\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_j)}^M \cdot a_j\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_j)}
$$
for all $i,j=1,\ldots,n$. In other words, the sections $s\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)} \cdot a_i$ glue to a section $b$ and since
$$
b\vert_{X_s\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)} = (s^M\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)} \cdot a_i)\vert_{X_s\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)}= s^{M+m}\vert_{X_s\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)} \cdot a\vert_{X_s\cap \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)}
$$
for $i=1,\ldots,n$, we conclude that $b\vert_{X_s}=s^{M+m}\vert_{X_s} \cdot a$.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It was late night here before 11 hours :)

Comment: I have added my idea as an answer as there is no enough space in comments section. Justification that the map is injective is mostly correct. Surjectivity is creating some problem.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Your proof for injectivity looks good. I added the details for the surjectivity.

Comment: I was about to type what I have got for surjectivity. I have got preimages for restrictions of a. Then I was not able to prove that these preimages can glue to get global section. I was thinking this is where I should use quasi separated thing but I was not able to do,, now it is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider restriction map $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow \Gamma(X_s,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Suppose $a\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be such that $a|_{X_s}=0$.

As $X_s=\{x\in X: s_x\notin \mathfrak{m}_x\subseteq \mathcal{O}_x\}$, $a|_{X_s}=0$ implies that $a_x=0\in A_x$ for every $x\in X_s$. By the observation as in the case of affine scheme this $a_x$ is identified with $\frac{a}{1}\in A_x$ which only means that $ta=0$ for some $t\notin x$. As $x\in X_s$ it means that, $s\notin x$. This does not say that $sa=0$ or $s^na=0$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. This approach does not give any information even in the case of affine schemes. Localizing at each element (prime ideal) in $X_s$ separately does not give enough information. We have to localize at an element of rings. Plan is to localize at restrictions of $s$ in elements in finite affine open cover of $X$.

As $X$ is quasi compact we have $X=\bigcup _{i=1}^r\text{Spec}(A_i)$ and that $X_s=\bigcup _{i=1}^r(X_s\cap \text{Spec}(A_i))$. Let $s_i=s|_{\text{Spec}(A_i)}$. Then $X_s\cap \text{Spec}(A_i)=D(s_i)$. As $a|_{X_s}=0$, this mean 
$a|_{X_s\cap \text{Spec}(A_i)}=0$ for each $1\leq i\leq r$. This means that $a_i|_{D(s_i)}=0$ where $a_i=a|_{\text{Spec}(A_i))}$. By observation as in question, $a_i|_{D(s_i)}=0$  means that $s_i^{n_i}a_i=0$ for some $n_i\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $n=\max\{n_i:1\leq i\leq r\}$. So, $s_i^na_i=0$ for every $q\leq i\leq r$ i.e., $(s^na)|_{\text{Spec}(A_i)}=0$ for every $1\leq i\leq r$. So, by identity axion, this means that $s^na=0$.